# Interactive matplotlib in Jupyter notebook with a shell command ' !python filename.py ' on remote server ssh -i access

Tags: matplotlib, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook, deep-learning-ami

Python code in PyCharm, I'm running on Jupyter Notebook - EC2 Instance (AWS Deep Learning AMI (Ubuntu 18.04)).

I'm successfully able to plot an interactive graph (onClick feature) in Jupiter notebook. But I have issue plotting an interactive graph when I run a .py file with the shell command in a notebook.

```
%matplotlib notebook
!python filename.py
```

Since I have code written in PyCharm its convenient to run the .py file as it has many imports and dependency and the interactive graph code is in another .py file that's called by other .py files.

I tired magic commands like below with no positive outcome.

```
%run filename.py
```

In all above tries, no graph plotted, and it skips the OnClick event, and the code fails with an error.

> IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2
> were indexed

Any suggestions would help.